# Как написать регулярное выражение на PHP для замены @ на текст?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на сайте https://regex101.com написать регулярное выражение для замены знака `@` на текст `instagram.com/»`.

Comment: Используйте [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: К сожалению, мне пока это ниочем не говорит. Я уже выбрал книгу для изучения регулярок "Регулярные выражения. Основы Автор: Майкл Фицджеральд Год выхода: 2015", но выражение мне нужно уже сегодня получить, поэтому к вам обратился.

Как получить выражение типа <a[^>]+?>([^<]+?)<\/a>[|]$1 , только для  замены @ на текст instagram.com/. Например ,было слово @vanechka, а стало instagram.com/vanechka

Comment: `$s = str_replace("@", "instagram/", $s);`

Comment: А как это превратить в такой вид, как это выражение? <div\s+id=[\'"]down[\'"]>(.+?)<\/div>[|]

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно так:

```
$text = 'Текст от @vanechka.';

$patt = '~@([^\s.,!?-]+)~iu';
$repl = 'instagram.com/$1';
$text = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: @Максим А. возможно ещё потребуется обернуть текст instagram.com/$1 в html теги, чтобы в результате получить гиперссылку.

Comment: кстати, можно обойтись без круглых скобок в регулярном выражении, если в строке подстановки заменить `$1` на `$0`

Comment: @mymedia без скобок вы получите полное соответствие с шаблоном, а надо отбрасывать "@".